# Special characters in root password in emergency mode

Tags: boot, password, special-characters

My debian is not starting well and go to `emergency mode` (with no possibility to avoid it :-(). In order to login, I need to be able to type my root password which contains special characters like `é`. How can I obtain these characters? I tried to go on grub console to try to type but I was not able to obtain the right characters...

Comment: Try [this link](https://www.linux.org/threads/alt-keys-and-linux.11517/) - It also has links for how to find special characters.

Comment: ... and be nicer to yourself, instead of using special characters such as diacriticals in a root password, which you know might be required when emergency dropping to console, just use a longer pure ascii password. Just saying...

Comment: And since you've now publicly discussed a password, changing it would be a good idea.  :)   Any possible security implications of using special characters are now negated, and a longer ascii password would be as secure or more secure.

Comment: @user10489 Your right :-) and I will actually not using special characters not available directly in a US/UK keyboard layout

Answer (score 1):

**At the console** you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>xyz (xyz are number on the numpad).

For example <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> should render `é`.

There are many sources for the list of codes, for example [this one](https://www.ascii-code.com/).

I don't know if it will work though, because depending on the locale, the actual password characters could be UTF-8 for example.

Comment: Are you sure about this? I can't reproduce this at all. Could it depend on your keyboard layout? I tried both in a tty and in a graphical terminal and nothing worked.

Comment: FWIW, using my left alt key I get one character, using the right alt key I get the correct one. For both of these situations I have to use the numpad, the normal numbers don't work.

Comment: Thanks @cutrightjm I should've mentioned the numpad.  Added.

Comment: @terdon I know it works in my Debian 10, after doing Ctrl-Alt-F1 (no, it will not work inside a graphic terminal).

Comment: Thank you for your proposition but currently it is not working. Probably because I use an apple keyboard...