# How do you type special characters in the logging prompt?

Tags: linux, shell, rescue

So I messed up my fstab, and now my computer will boot into the "rescue" mode

However, me being a bit clumsy, I have some special characters in my password (namely à and À). Is there a way I can type those in or am I just screwed ?

Comment: Would this thread help you ? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/652478/special-characters-in-root-password-in-emergency-mode

Comment: @MC68020 It actually worked, tysm you saved me from a headache. My bad for not searching with the correct terms I guess, and sorry for the duplicate

Comment: No worry ! Your question is not actually a duplicate since the solution suggested had not been successful for many. Happy it worked for you… it is definitely **not** good practice to… catch a headache **before** end-of-year parties… ;-)